# Pandas multi column input to multi column output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find a good way to run a (nonlinear, injective, multivariable) transformation on columns in a pandas dataframe. Transform is a black box with multiple variables in and multiple variables out.

As an easy illustration, let's just consider converting r, theta coordinates to x, y coordinates. Run this for setup/context

```
# set up example (all this is given in my case)
def blackbox_transform(rtheta):
    x = rtheta[0]*np.cos(rtheta[1])
    y = rtheta[0]*np.sin(rtheta[1])
    return (x, y)
n = 50
r = np.ones(n)
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi / 2, n)
r_theta = np.concatenate((r[:, None], theta[:, None]), axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=r_theta, columns=['r', 'theta'])
```

For the solution, this is the best I can come up with, but the apply and unpacking seems clunky (hoping a pandas wizard has a better approach):

```
# solution
xy = df[['r', 'theta']].apply(blackbox_transform, axis=1)
df = pd.concat((df, pd.DataFrame(data=[*xy], columns=['x', 'y'], index=xy.index)), axis=1)
```

I get that using pandas may look a little silly here, but there's a lot of other information I have in the dataframe and I need to transform some numerics columns while keeping all the indices and other info straight.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more readable approach:

```
out = df[['r', 'theta']].apply(rtheta_to_xy, 1).apply(pd.Series)                               
df = df.assign(x=out[0], y=out[1])
```

Btw your use of `lambda` is dispensable when you are just forwarding the same argument.

Comment: It is slightly more readable, good suggestion. Also, good point on the lambda.  I initially made the example with arguments to unpack and absent-mindedly forgot the lambda is worthless once I inherently packed them together -- doh.